Having trouble querying multiple custom taxonomies
Currently trying to find only posts that match multiple custom taxonomies however im getting zero posts every time i try. How can i filter these multiple taxonomies using the and relation if some taxonomies will be left blank in the query. I need to be able to get all posts that match the theme health in life sciences at the boston campus for example. This should only return exact matches only 
// Start output buffer to capture HTML
ob_start();
$tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : array();
$lowercase_terms = array_map('strtolower', $tags);
$trimmed_terms = array_map('trim', $lowercase_terms);

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'nu_institutes',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
);


if (!empty($trimmed_terms)) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nu_institutes-tags',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $trimmed_terms,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nu_institutes-themes',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $trimmed_terms,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nu_institutes-subjects',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $trimmed_terms,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nu_institutes-campuses',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $trimmed_terms,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    );
}

$posts_query = new WP_Query($args);


Basically lets say my array of terms i send in contains ['health', 'boston'] I need to return all of the posts that contain health AND boston. I know currently this returns zero posts because it's expecting to match terms on all taxonomies

$_POST['tags'] is always a string but you treat it as an array, which means the value "test" becomes [ "t", "e", "s", "t" ], your PHP error log should be full of warnings about this. Also your logic is super strict, you've asked for posts that have a term in all of those taxonomies to be included! Usually people make that mistake because they muddle up AND/OR using the human common way of saying it, not logic. AND means all clauses have to match

@TomJNowell Post['tags'] is an array received from an ajax call lol. This filter works with OR but i need AND logic for this query. I need to return all posts that only contain all of the terms sent in in any of the taxonomies.

I'm trying to retrieve all posts that contain all of the terms in the array in any of the taxonomies so that is what I'm looking for direction on.

I understand, what I mean is that AND in conversational human language means slightly different things to AND in computers. It'll become more obvious if we use examples, can you provide some? e.g. "the value is allowed to be A and B and C" means if ( value == A OR value == B OR value == C ). It's a super common misunderstanding.

also have you accounted for spaces and hyphens? Life Sciences for example would be searched as life sciences in your code but WP would use life-sciences as the slug. I assume all the checkboxes have the same tags name? Would it be possible to change that so each type of filter has separate names? Currently there's no way of knowing if life-sciences is a term in a taxonomy without doing extra DB queries that slow things down, which is a hard requirement if you want to account for someone not adding a subjects filter.

@TomJNowell the taxonomies and terms supplied to the filter work fine. I'm just having a hard time figuring out the logic to return posts that contain all of the supplied taxonomies in 'tags' using AND logic and not OR. Or returns posts with any of the tags and I need only specific posts that contain all of the tags in the supplied array using any of the above taxonomies
